# Datepicker Wedget restrict random dates

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

Looking at the Datepicker Widget from JQuery Mobile - need to be able to restrict the date selections to only Sundays from a start date to an end date. and also restrict every third Thursday during a 12 month period. I only see date range to view calendars not the ability to restrict select days?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Restrict date range</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {
  $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ minDate: -20, maxDate: "+1M +10D" });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide an implementation of the `beforeShowDay` method.  You can implement your custom logic to return the array with true on the first index only when the day should be selectable.

```
A function that takes a date as a parameter and must return an array with:
  [0]: true/false indicating whether or not this date is selectable
  [1]: a CSS class name to add to the date's cell or "" for the default presentation
  [2]: an optional popup tooltip for this date
The function is called for each day in the datepicker before it is displayed.
```

See the [JQueryUI API documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay) for more information.

Comment: I just found that function - guess I'm now looking for a way to generate an array of dates for a select year that only occur on Sundays or every third Thursday. (Still not clear on the 0: 1: 2: of the function, is this positions within the array?

Comment: The way I read it, if you return `[false, "", "Not Allowed"]` from that function, it would disallow all dates in the widget.  All you'd need to do is check the `date` object (which gets passed into your method as a parameter) against your business logic and determine when it's appropriate to return that response vs. an allowed response.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final code to show how this can be accomplished, still will need work to exclude dates for an entire year, but seem to be do-able. I have included a [JSFiddle - datepicker](http://jsfiddle.net/jeffbarclay/v5rb2Lpa/4/)

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Restrict date range</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
  var unavailableDates = [
    new Date(2014, 0, 23).valueOf(),
    new Date(2014, 11, 25).valueOf(),
    new Date(2014, 7, 14).valueOf()
  ];

function unavailable(date) {
if (date.getDay() === 4 && $.inArray(date.valueOf(), unavailableDates) < 0) {
    return [true, ""];
} else {
    return [false, "", "Unavailable"];
}
}

$(document).ready(function() {
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: unavailable
});
});
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>


</body>
</html>
```